# How to remove the panel from the panel it attached to in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I have met a serious problem with my Java swing.

This is how I initialize my chart, everything seems fine now, `xyChartPanel` is declared as a `JPanel` in the field, I initialize it with the `xyChart` I just created. When this step is done, I am okay to see the chart (painted to `xyChartPanel`) centered to the `JPanel` I am writing code on, see `add(xyChartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);`.

```
private void initXYChart() {
        // Create Chart
        xyChart = new XYChartBuilder().width(800).height(800).xAxisTitle(xColName).yAxisTitle("Y").build();

        // Customize Chart
        xyChart.getStyler().setLegendPosition(LegendPosition.InsideNE);
        xyChart.getStyler().setAxisTitlesVisible(true);
        xyChart.getStyler().setDefaultSeriesRenderStyle(XYSeriesRenderStyle.Line);

        double[] yCoordArray = new double[xCoordArray.length];

        // Loop through the series
        for (int i = 0; i < yCoordinates.size(); i++) {
            List<Double> yCoordOneSeries = yCoordinates.get(i);
            // Convert list to array
            for (int j = 0; j < yCoordArray.length; j++) {
                yCoordArray[j] = yCoordOneSeries.get(j);
            }
            xyChart.addSeries(yColNames.get(i), xCoordArray, yCoordArray);
        }

        xyChartPanel = new XChartPanel<>(xyChart);
        add(xyChartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        xyChart.getStyler().setDefaultSeriesRenderStyle(XYSeriesRenderStyle.Area);

        add(xyChartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
```

Now the problem comes, I don't want my chart to be unchanged all the time, actually I want to change the style of my chart responded to my action on the radio buttons.

I just wrote the `updateChartPanelStyle(JRadioButton styleButton)` method that takes

```
private void updateChartPanelStyle(JRadioButton styleButton) {
        String style = styleButton.getText();
        if (styleButton.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println(style);
            switch (style) {
            case "Line":
                xyChart.getStyler().setDefaultSeriesRenderStyle(XYSeriesRenderStyle.Line);
                break;
            case "Area":
                xyChart.getStyler().setDefaultSeriesRenderStyle(XYSeriesRenderStyle.Area);
                break;
            case "Scatter":
                xyChart.getStyler().setDefaultSeriesRenderStyle(XYSeriesRenderStyle.Scatter);
            }

            xyChartPanel = new XChartPanel<>(xyChart);
            add(xyChartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    }
```

See in this method, I changed the style of `xyChart` I initialized in the last function, and reinitialize the `xyChartPanel`, then add the updated `xyChartPanel` to the working panel. Interestingly, I didn't see any change in my GUI. I thought this might be a problem with my `xyChart` whose style could not be changed afterward. But this is not really the case.

Even if I "removed" `xyChartPanel` with `this.remove(xyChartPanel);`, the GUI doesn't seems to be changed.

This is really weird, what should I do now?

Comment: How do you call `updateChartPanelStyle` in your code?

Comment: I'm not sure you need to make a new XChartPanel every time you want to change it, perhaps just set the render style and call repaint

Answer (score 1):

Every time you add/remove components to swing dynamically, you need to call `revalidate();` and then `repaint();` on your JPanel (or JFrame if you're adding it straight to that).

Comment: (1+) You only need to invoke the revalidate() and repaint() on the panel you changed.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for pointing that out! That's what I had intended to say. Fixed now.